# Can I Create/List Pods in Azure AKS without Installing Kubelogin, Similar to EKSHook in Amazon, Using Airflow?

Tags: azure, airflow, azure-aks

I'm currently working on a project where I need to create and list pods in Azure AKS using Airflow. I know that there is a way in Amazon using EKSHook without the need for an extra installation like 'kubelogin'.

Is there a similar method or any way possible to accomplish the same task in Azure AKS?

Any guidance or insights from someone who has faced a similar situation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

In order to use AKS from Airflow, I had to install az cli and kubelogin. It works but this seems like a overhead when trying to control AKS from Airflow. I asked chat gpt and searched google if there was any alternatives but could not find any.

Comment: there isn't any direct equivalent of the Amazon EKSHook for AKS. However, you can try exploring Azure SDK for Python (azure-mgmt-containerinstance or azure-mgmt-kubernetes as an alternative option.

Comment: I tried to use the Azure SDK for Python but it still seems like I have to install az cli and kubelogin to be able to use the SDK to connect to AKS. I may be wrong so If there are alternative way to do this without installing kubelogin please let me know. Thanks

Comment: check if this helps using api- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/list-cluster-user-credentials?view=rest-aks-2023-08-01&tabs=HTTP

By the way I tried with sdk and it is able list the details https://i.imgur.com/QR2Fqo5.png

Comment: Okay I found another way, using service principal- https://i.imgur.com/dgTfdT2.png

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent of the Amazon EKSHook for AKS without installing kubelogin or az cli. However, you can try exploring [Azure SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-overview) (azure-mgmt-containerinstance or azure-mgmt-kubernetes as an alternative option. Another way is by using service principal
[image]

I tried with sdk and it is able list the details.
[image]

Using airflow you can connect to aks api server using the azure python sdk.

install the necessary libraries

```
pip install azure-mgmt-containers azure-identity kubernetes
```

***Using Default credentials***

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice.models import ManagedCluster

# Authenticate
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()


subscription_id = "your_subscription_id"
resource_group = "your_resource_group"
cluster_name = "your_cluster_name"

# Create a ContainerServiceClient
client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Get information about the AKS cluster
cluster = client.managed_clusters.get(resource_group, cluster_name)

print(f"AKS Cluster Name: {cluster.name}")
print(f"AKS Cluster Location: {cluster.location}")
print(f"AKS Cluster Kubernetes Version: {cluster.kubernetes_version}")
```

or
***using service principal credentials***

```py
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient

  

# Authenticate to Azure using a service principal

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(

client_id="<your-client-id>",

client_secret="<your-client-secret>",

tenant_id="your-tenant-id"

)

  

client = ContainerServiceClient(credentials, subscription_id="<your-subscription-id>"
)

  

# List nodes

nodes = client.managed_clusters.list_cluster_node_details(resource_group_name="<your-resource-group-name>", cluster_name="<your-cluster-name>")

  

for node in nodes:

print(node.name)

print(node.os_type)

print(node.provisioning_state)

print(node.power_state)

print(node.agent_version)

print(node.kubelet_version)

print(node.conditions)

print(node.tags)

print(node.location)

print(node.id)

print(node.type)
```

Reference Documents:

[Azure python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-overview)

[Managed Clusters - List Cluster User Credentials - REST API (Azure AKS) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/list-cluster-user-credentials?view=rest-aks-2023-08-01&tabs=HTTP)

[Airflow on AKS](https://medium.com/@chen_13104/airflow-on-azure-kubernetes-part-1-6ded98d6b8d6)